# JPA Selecting only one argument in a column and put it in a String

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I´m wondering if it is possible to select just one specific argument from a column that contains more than one value. After, I want to put it in a `String` or an array of `String`s.

Suppose that I have a column called `names` with three values. I want the second name.

Comment: Are you using the criteria api from JPA (CriteriaBuilder etc.) or are you sing the Java Persistence query language?

Comment: Often times you can write a native query to select a specific field from your entity, or write a JPA query like `SELECT user.name FROM UserEntity user WHERE user.id = :userId`. See [here](http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/specific-columns-jpa-native-query/) for an example.

Comment: Whats mean 'one argument in a column'??

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I am using the Java Persistence query

Comment: @Liuk For example I have a Table with a column called "Name". In this column I have 3 names. Now I want to select only the second Name.

Comment: @Cryses how are the names separated?

Comment: @Liuk They aren't. That's why I asked if it is possible. I think I need to get a String Array of the column. Therefore I can select them separately => s[1] s[3]  
But I dont know how I Select a column and transform it into a  String Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you have in your db a table, like `User` with columns `id` and `names`, you can create a native query using JPA.

```
@Query(value="select names from user u where u.id =:userId", nativeQuery=true)
String getNames(@Param("userId") long userId);
```

This method return a `String`. Now, you can create an array of names using the method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) provided by Java 7.

```
String names = myRepository.getNames(userId);
String[] namesList = names.split(" "); // Split on whitespaces
```

Comment: I got the error message, that `@Query` and `@Param` cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Maybe you don't have imported correctly the library

Comment: http://philip.yurchuk.com/2008/12/03/eclipse-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error/